# Create review board request after SVN commit

Tags: svn, review-board

I have a SVN ready on server and it is getting used daily. We have successfully installed review board and integrated SVN with it, with post hook strategy. But now we want that whenever a change is commited to SVN a new review request must get generated automatically.

Anybody has idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to generate it after commit ?It's possible to generate review request before commit and others can review those changes. Once you are fixed all the reviews comments   you're ready to check in.

Comment: Yes, I want to generate it after commit.

Comment: Usually Review board is used for reviewing code changes done after last checkin. You have to add a .bat file in the working folder and run it. On running this, a mail will be sent to all the team members. 

I don't  think it's possible to generate it after commit. 

If you require the .bat file, pls comment.(It works as I mentioned above)

Comment: Thank you Sudix for your response but while surfing on reviewboard site, I found we can do post commit review, on following link [https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.0/users/tools/post-review/#posting-committed-code](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.0/users/tools/post-review/#posting-committed-code). I think I will first give this a try.